# Simple way of evaluating the integral $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\left(1-x^2\right)}{(1-\alpha x)^3} d x$?

Tags: integration

Is there a simple method to evaluate the integral $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\left(1-x^2\right)}{(1-\alpha x)^3} d x,$$ other than doing integration by parts, maybe, by differentiating w.r.t $\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a real parameter?

Comment: Why not just expand using partial fractions? Then you're just integrating $\frac{1}{(1 - \alpha x)^k}$, $k=1,2,3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More general, we can solve the indefinite integral. Let $t=1-\alpha x,$

$$I=-\frac{1}\alpha\int \frac{1-\left(\frac{1-t}{\alpha} \right)^2}{t^3}dt=-\frac{1}{\alpha^3}\int \frac{\alpha^2-1-t^2+2t}{t^3}dt=\frac{1}{\alpha^3}\left(\frac{\alpha^2-1}{2t^2}+\frac{2}t+\ln |t|\right)$$